# how to split String in to two different text veiw

Tags: android

I am getting this data from server

```
{
  "CrewComplement":" (LS) UTKARSH KUMAR(UKUMAR)\\n (C2) AMANDEEP   WALIA(AMANDI)\\n (C2) KHUSHBOO VERMA-118(KHUSVE)\\n (C2) MOMO ZELIANG(MOMOZE)\\n (C1) NARENDRA KUMAR(NAREND)"
}
```

I would like to display them into two text box one is (LS) and other one is (CS)...
how I can split this one?

Comment: you need to get data in json format from server...

Comment: MustanserIqbal. You are right. @Ullas Ms ash your server side people to give JSON format result. Please look at this link to understand JSON format." http://www.w3schools.com/json/ " And parse the data using android api's like "http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm"

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to solve it is to change the response that the server sends. Once split into two (or more) rows, you will be able to parse it using org.json library, [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) and more.

If you cannot modify the response, you can simply use the [substring](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29) method, though it's a patch rather than a solution.

Comment: I am not getting to use sub string if you any sample can u post

Comment: myString.substring(startIndex, endIndex);